# Перехват сокета

Tags: winsock, c++, visual-c++

Суть задачи такова: из приложения необходимо запустить любым возможным способом клиент-программу (самостоятельное приложение), которая работает с сетью и перехватить (скопировать) ее сокет чтобы в дальнейшем через него (от имени клиента) `отсылать` необходимые пакеты на сервер так, чтобы сервер не догадался о подмене отправителя и не разорвал соединение. Или же внедрить в процесс клиента свою DLL, чтобы манипулировать его сокетом. `Путь решения не важен важен результат`. Кто может дельно подсказать или поделиться умными ссылками по этой теме, буду весьма благодарен.

P.S: Результатом всего этого должен получится небольшой игровой бот, по скрипту отсылающий статичные пакеты серверу (скрипт система boost::python), ОС Windows XP.

Comment: Программа, в которую вы хотите внедриться ваша? Вы можете внести изменения в ее код?

Comment: а может проще написать свой "проксик" ?

Comment: Толком не пойму чего Вы хотите. Предположим это TCP.

Вам надо запустить программу (.exe), которая делает **connect()** и возможно инициализацию прикладного уровня (подозреваю, что ради нее все затевается). После этого Вы хотите обмениваться с сервером пакетами в заголовке которых host:port, полученные от ОС этой программой.

Так ? Или еще в прикладном протоколе есть какие-то неизвестные Вам  тонкости, которые эта программа обеспечивает ?

Comment: была бы клиент-программа моей (или наличие ее исходников) вопросов бы небыло...
тонкостей как таковых кроме строения пакетов не знаю мб чего и наворочего что вероятнее всего... перехватывать все происходящее с сокетом клиента мне не нужно, нужно только отсылать через него свои пакеты..
 Т.Е надо внердиться в клиент-сокет и через него СЛАТЬ пакеты (socket->send) все что дальше будет просиходить с сокетом клиент обрабатывает сам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В случае `win` самый простой спобоб - поставить хуки на функции `send` и `receive` библиотеки `winsock`. В этом случае можно просто хукать их, например, с помощью библиотеки [**`detours`**](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/), или, например, воспользоваться [`asm`-трамплином.](http://somebastardstolemyname.wordpress.com/2008/07/27/c-send-hook/)

---

Понятно, что проблема **в общем случае** усложняется различными версиями `winsock`, а также тем, что игры обычно делают не дураки и применяется SSL шифрование. Во втором случае иногда *(особенно, если можно патчить исходный игровой клиент)* возможно проведение хитрой атаки `MITM (Man-In-The-Middle)` со спуфингом `X509` сертификатов и написанием промежуточного сервера.

Подробнее про это *(но это уже совсем айс)* - на примере клиента `PokerStars` - http://daeken.com/reversing-the-pokerstars-protocol-part-1-comp, там же есть и исходники соответствующих промежуточного сервера и описано, как делается подмена сертификата.

Comment: Насчет хуков - это интересно, а вот с промежуточным сервером боюсь ничего не выйдет, но в любом случае изучу предложенную информацию. Благодарю.